# Can an htaccess redirect load an url lower in the path?

Tags: .htaccess

If I have an url of, for example, '/test/' is it possible (and if so, how) to use an .htaccess redirect to load an url of, for example, '/test/1/'?

Update in response to questions from @Michael Berkowski in the comments below...

Question: Does the URL /test/1/ exist, or are you trying to use it as the browser's address only?

The url exists (albeit with a different name, example: /april-4-10-2016/mon/) as a page within a WordPress install. It displays one day of a week-to-view schedule for a radio station.

The page content is the schedule for the first day of that week, with links to the other days.

Currently, those links work in the daily pages, but not the week page (for which, instead of /test/, an example url is /april-4-10-2016/). This is because of the way the nav menu is constructed to auto-add the parent url) and hence there's some sense in forwarding the weekly page to that of the first day.

So an example of the actual forwarding, rather than /test/ to test/1/, is /april-4-10-2016/ to /april-4-10-2016/mon/.

Question: Do you want to redirect everything to /test/1 or only some input URLs?

Only selected urls, and as noted above, I used /test/ and /test/1/ in the question to find out how in principle this might be done, so that I can then construct required redirects as they're needed.

Question: What exact URL sent by the user's browser resutls in a) what exact internal URL for your site and b) what exact URL in the browser address bar?

If I've understood and answered this correctly, the /test/ url will forward to and load /test/1/ (or, with a real example /april-4-10-2016/ will forward to and load /april-4-10-2016/mon/) and the address bar will show the url of the page being viewed (so the viewer knows where they are, with nothing hidden).

Comment: Please add more details - these things are possible, but we need more specifics. Does the URL /test/1/ exist, or are you trying to use it as the browser's address only? Do you want to redirect everything to /test/1 or only some input URLs? What exact URL sent by the user's browser resutls in a) what exact internal URL for your site and b) what exact URL in the browser address bar?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski... thanks. I've added detail to the original question.